# Using ng-model with multiple javascript files for one shared html file

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have one html file that has a ng-model binding like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ClassA.phoneNumber"/>
```

Can I use another js file to bind with the same element? Something like?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ClassA.phoneNumber || ClassB.PhoneNumber"/>
```

The thing is I don't want to create another HTML file just for binding a simple element. The html file is being reused by multiple js files.

Comment: you have to use ngSwitch or ngIf instead.

Comment: @pbachman should i use a combination of ngIf and model? like ngIf = ClassA ngModel = ClassA.phoneNumber on one html element, and ngIf =ClassB ngModel = classB.phonenumber on the other?

Comment: i don't know how your html looks like, but you could do it like this <div ng-if="ClassA.phoneNumber">
<input type="text" ng-model="ClassA.phoneNumber" />
<div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know how your html looks like, but you could do it like this

```
<input type="text" ng-if="ClassA.phoneNumber" ng-model="ClassA.phoneNumber" />
<input type="text" ng-if="ClassB.phoneNumber" ng-model="ClassB.phoneNumber" />
```

angular will remove the dom element, if the condition is not met